# does sqllite work well in pos desktop application

Tags: flutter, sqlite, rdbms, desktop, sqflite

I'm currently working on a desktop POS application using flutter
and the application does not necessarily need an internet connection or networking at all
it works locally

I have choosen sqlite (sqflite for flutter)  as a local databse for the application

so the question is

does sqlite works well for such kind of applications
or I should consider using one of the RDBMSs available ??

Comment: If your app will never have multi-user concurrent, you can go with SQLite. Otherwise, you need to build server-client app with rdbms; server for directly communicate with rdbms, client to communicate to server.

Comment: the application is entirely local and the local database has only one client which is the application itself @ישואוהבאותך

Comment: You can go with SQLite. But, always separate your database access code to a specific helper class or file. Don't directly use db in your widget. So, when in the future you needed to use rdbms or switch to server-client  for allowing multi-user (which usually needed in Restaurant POS),  then you just need to change the helper class.